# Determine ASUS Transformer Serial Number

Tags: asus-eee-pad-transformer

I'm trying to determine the model of an ASUS Transformer tablet.

In Settings -> About, I know its a TF-101 (I knew this one I bought it a few years ago). But that's all it provides under Android 4.0.3 (shown below).

However, I cannot determine if its an A20, B10, etc. According to [How to identify hardware versions?](http://www.transformerforums.com/forum/asus-transformer-tf101-general-discussions/3661-how-identify-hardware-versions.html), its encoded in the serial number, and its on a sticker attached to the tablet. Unfortunately, even with my glasses, I cannot seem to find it.

How does one determine the serial number for an ASUS TF-101 tablet?

---

[image]

Comment: It should be under "Status" in the "About tablet" menu.  Have you looked in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be under "Status", in the "About tablet" menu.