# Is it possible to extract Nexus 7 serial number through command line (e.g., ADB)?

Tags: nexus-7, screen

I'm possibly into a rare situation. I have a Nexus 7 LTE 2013 that suddenly stopped showing anything on the screen. It looks like turned off all the time, even the LED light does not turn on. I tried charging it in various ways and it did not help.

I contacted Asus and they asked me for the serial number, which I don't have. They said I can find this on the box, which I don't have either.

Using ADB, while N7 is connected to my Macbook Air, I did `adb devices` and it shows up a device that is "offline". When issuing the command `adb get-serialno`, it says unknown. It looks like the device is not dead but probably the screen is.

Is there any tool that can get me the serial number through command line?

**Update:**

I had an alarm set on the device. Today the alarm was fired and I heard the alarm ring from the device. I could only turn off the alarm by holding the power button.

Comment: *"...suddenly stopped showing anything on the screen. It looks like turned off all the time"* - I have to provide this as a comment because its not an answer to your primary question. I experienced this issue on two different TF-101 tablets. The first one I had to send back for replacement. The second happened recently when trying to enter bootloader screen manually. After trying to enter the bootloader screen, I found I had to hold the POWER button for 10 seconds to get the device to start. The momentary presses, and the press and hold for 1 second, did not work.

Comment: *"I contacted Asus and they asked me for the serial number, which I don't have. They said I can find this on the box, which I don't have either"* - also see [Determine ASUS Transformer Serial Number](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/79558/determine-asus-transformer-serial-number) when you get the device powered up.

Comment: @jww Yes you certainly need to hold the power button for some time. And, determination of the serial number on the screen is of course not an option for now. Thanks for the comment anyway.

Comment: *Yes you certainly need to hold the power button for some time"* - did it boot for you?

Comment: @jww since "adb devices" returns something but it says the device is offline, it looks like the device is actually turned on.

Comment: @ Hussain - OK man. Sorry to waste your time. Good luck with your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "device offline" output means that the device is detected, but it refuses any operation because the user didn't allow that particular computer to connect ([secure ADB](http://nelenkov.blogspot.hu/2013/02/secure-usb-debugging-in-android-422.html?m=1)). Your device is up and running, and displaying a confirmation window on its non-functioning screen. You could try to power the device on and blindly hit the OK button after unlocking the screen, then all ADB commands should work. Alternatively, if you have used ADB with another computer, try it with that.

Also, all devices offer some kind of ID even in this state, displayed by "adb devices"; this is the serial number most of the time. See if it's the right format.

Edit: "fastboot devices" should show the serial number too. Also, it should be easy to put the N7 into fastboot mode even without a screen.

Comment: I used the number that came out from "adb devices" and provided it to their agent, he said this is not the right format.

Comment: When using fastboot, I got this: $fastboot devices
ERROR: could not get pipe properties

Comment: I haven't yet met that error message, and it seems to be OSX specific after a bit of googling. One site suggests running fastboot as root - it will probably give you the same number as ADB, but it's worth a shot. Did you put the device into fastboot mode?

Comment: Also, running the command `adb shell getprop | grep serial` should show at least two entries, but first you have to get ADB access by blindly tapping that OK button. Also, it may be the case that the serial number in Android from the one you're after. [(source, post #12; although it's for N7 2012)](http://forums.androidcentral.com/google-nexus-7-tablet-2012/208120-finding-nexus-7-serial-number.html)

Comment: thanks for the help and follow up, I think your answer is actually nearest to the solution. I finally figured out an extremely lightly printed serial no on the back of the device, called them and they accepted it as the device's serial no.

Comment: You're welcome, and I'm glad your problem was solved :)